# Free tool to change a coloured logo to white/transparent?

Tags: color, logo, software-recommendation, tools

I'm doing some website design for a client and they want the companies that sell their product to be listed on a page. The problem is they don't want the exact company logo on the page, they want it to blend with their website colour scheme. I need a way to change a logo to transparent background and make it all white.

Example of what they want
[image: Example of what they want]

Logo they want changed
[image: Logo they want changed]

Essentially, the yellow needs to be white, the red in the logo needs to be transparent, the "hh" logo stays white and the writing is white and everything else it transparent. Is there a free tool I could use to do this?

Thanks

Comment: There's no quick, easy way to do that.  You can download [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), but you will still have to do some manual editing to cut out the red and make it transparent.  Converting the colors to white is easy, once that's finished

Comment: Many companies have strict rules of usage over their logos. For example, the Costco logo must be presented in red (Costco) and blue (Wholesale) or all in black. One cannot use it any other way. I imagine that goes for a lot of other companies, as well.

Comment: Good to know, I will check the usage rights

Comment: What is the reason behond the explicit request for a *free* tool? With software, as with other things in life, you get what you pay for. And a distinct disadvantage of free software is that you won't be getting your money back if not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since these are raster (non-vector) you can use [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/).